# Communication between child iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

I have built a player which is embedded via an iframe. If two players are embedded, I want to stop one if the other starts to play. So the question is, is it possible to use `postMessage` to communicate between two children iframes, without owning the parent? Vimeo is doing this somehow. If I embed two vimeo players, and play one, then the other, the second player stops the first. How? (proof: https://jsfiddle.net/3fy14orw/2/)

Within my player, I am using `postMessage` to fire off an event on the parent window when my player plays. I've confirmed this is working. I've tried using my actual origin as well as "*" for the origin.

```
//in my player
window.parent.postMessage(data, "*");
```

How can the other player know? I've tried,

```
//tried adding this in my player    
window.parent.addEventListener('message', function(evt) {});
```

But this throws an error.

```
"SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin..."
```

I've also tried naming my frame windows, as well as accessing these via the window.parent.frames object, but this also throws a CORS issue.

Assumptions:

- My players share the same origin.
- My player can be embedded on any domain, not just my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda hacky, but you could build a communication channel on top of [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Frames could send messages by writing to localStorage, and then read messages by constantly polling localStorage for changes.

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. This is how Vimeo is accomplishing it. Checked LocalStorage based on your answer, and sure enough they are setting an active state.

Comment: Works like a charm. Not sure what negative effects could come from polling via setInterval, but things seem smooth to me.